# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something' while saving

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have very simple model -

```
> class Item(TimeStampedModel):
    item_name = models.CharField("Item name", max_length=100)
    item_urlname = models.CharField("Item url name", null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
    item_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    standard = models.ManyToManyField(Standard, blank = True, null = True)
    item_type = models.CharField("Item Type", choices=ITEM_TYPES, max_length=5, default='P')
```

I have save override for it -

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    try:
        url_nosymbols = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', '', self.item_name.lower())                    
        url = url_nosymbols.replace(' ','_')
        self.item_urlname = url
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        raise
```

Now when I try to save the Item using shell_plus (Item object is imported along with all the other objects), it fails with the weird error - **Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sub'**

```
>import re
>item = Item(item_name='my testing', item_date=datetime.now().date(), item_type='C')
>item.save()
>url_nosymbols = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', '', self.item_name.lower()) 
 *** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sub'
```

even though when I check self is Item object, and it does exists -

```
(Pdb) self
<Init: my testing>
(Pdb) type(self)
<class 'items.models.Item'>
(Pdb) self.item_name
'my testing'
```

I feel like, there is some other error but its not throwing actual error. I see this exact error message been asked for few questions on other stack overflow threads, though I am not able to relate with my scenario.

Thanks in advance for the help. Any additional question, please throw in comment, I'll try to make the information available.

Comment: What's the output if you type `re` in pdb? You may want to print it in several points in your code, because I suppose the last one will only print `None`.

Comment: Looks like a problem with `re`. Could you add the version of Python and the output of `type(re)` and maybe `dir(re)`?

Comment: A few observations: in your example you have an equality test rather than assignment `item_date==datetime.now().date()`. You should also lower case all your property names and the try/except isn't doing anything. You want to check `item_name` isn't `None` before calling `lower()`.

Comment: @AndrewS- thats typo as I was changing the variable names etc, I am fixing it right away. also in this particular case there is value for item_name as you can see on the pdb.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida- output of re is - <module 're' from '/Users/J/Apps/labs/watson/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, as I suspected issue was somewhere else. After few debugging sessions I was able to figure out that it was happening because of circular Foreign key reference on the page (I had another model in the page where it had circular reference to Item). However, I am still interested in knowing why it didn't throw the actual error and keep showing this confusing message. Thanks for taking time to going thru the question, hopefully it might be helpful to someone else.